# How do I get 10km eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to know how to get a 10km egg. I like the 2km and the 5km, but I want a 10km as well. I have been collecting 2km and 5km all the time, but I don't know where the much rarer 10km are.

Comment: You collect them the same way you collect 2km and 5km eggs.

Comment: Very helpful of you... but what chances/type of pokestops or time playability does it take to get one?

Comment: @ottome there are different types of pokestops?

Comment: I think he means what level do you have to be before they start appearing?

Comment: Is there a certain pokestop I have to go to? I have been to every type of pokestop in the city to suburban neighborhoods and nothing.

Comment: @ottome: When you say "every type of pokestop", what is it that you mean, exactly? Because there's really no difference between pokestops other than location. The other points of interest in the game are gyms, but they're not pokestops.

Comment: You're just unlucky, keep trying. I got a 10k on my very first pokestop spin, but then did not receive a 2nd one until a full week later of playing. It's all random.

Answer (score 11):

**A 10km egg is obtained randomly from a PokeStop. There are no other requirements other than spinning the PokeStop.**

Similar to 2km and 5km eggs, you have a chance of receiving a 10km egg from any PokeStop. There are no requirements to obtain the egg other than spinning the PokeStop, but you'll notice that they are generally significantly more rare than the other eggs. The location of the PokeStop  or your level does not matter (or at least has not yet been proven to matter).

There isn't much factual data on the rate of obtaining the eggs as of now. You can read an interesting discussion about the rate [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4une01/what_is_the_probability_of_receiving_a_10k_egg/), but consider this as a discussion and not a source of reliable data. There are many theories but nothing has been confirmed. You may be able to find an Excel sheet in the depths of the Internet that backs up the 4% chance mentioned in that thread, or you could create your own and calculate your results.

Comment: So it's that rare to find a 10k egg? 4%? So you can run into one like once or twice a month? How rare exactly is that in days. I can only find 2k and 5k at the moment, and it's really frustrating. Do dropping lucky eggs increase your chances of finding them besides gaining xp?

Comment: Still no 10k egg. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you received one yet, @ottome? No, lucky eggs do not increase the chance of receiving a 10k egg.

And no - a 4% chance doesn't necessarily mean that. It means that you'll receive a 10km egg once per 25 eggs on average.

Answer (score -2):

I get 10km eggs when I have hatched all my 2km eggs and there are only 5km eggs left to hatch. I have tested this theory four times now and always end up with a 10km egg. Normally as soon as the last 2km egg hatches and there are eight 5km eggs ready for hatching I will receive a 10km egg at the next Pokestop. You may not need eight 5km eggs, but that's what I always appear to have. So hatch all your 2km eggs and see what happens!

Comment: This is definitely coincidental. It's truly just randomly determined.

Comment: I have had received 10km eggs while I still had 2km eggs; as recently as last week, in fact. I also often have only 7 or 8 5km eggs and have gotten only 5km eggs, so that doesn't guarantee a 10km egg either.

Comment: I have 9 5km eggs right now. By this logic, that should be impossible.